# django and csrf_token problem

Tags: python, django, token

I have a little problem with the token in django.

When I write a POST form  and add {{csrf_token}}, when I submit it the token is checked .

But when I send a POST request (in ajax) and add  the paramater manually **csrfmiddlewaretoken** , the token is not checked.

But I don't know why ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

AJAX requests are not checked for CSRF: the browser's same origin policy means that CSRF attacks are much harder. See [the explanation in the docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/contrib/csrf/#ajax).

Comment: OK, but if I use an old browser, in those the Ajax Cross Domain  will  work, no ?

Comment: No. It's newer browsers that have relaxed the same-origin policy under certain limited circumstances: older browsers are strict.

Comment: Ah ok, thanks.

But then, do you know if there is any plans, in a future django version, to check it since our browsers allow it ?